# Redirecting a Preview DNS subdomain to a domain with htaccess

Tags: htaccess, redirects, wordpress, 301-redirect

I want to redirect all the WordPress urls of the form

`http://example.com.previewdns.com/my-favorite-post/`  to

`http://example.com/my-favorite-post/`

I am trying to do this with the below .htaccess code.. But its not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com.previewdns.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^example\.com\.previewdns\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi !Thanks for the reply. I've tried your code. It's not working!

Comment: Well what happens then? What does the resulting URL look like?